# What is the best practice to navigate Home Page and page in sub folder?

Tags: php, html

This is simple question but I am looking for best solution for the issue.

I have below html code on painting page.

```
<a href="home.php">Home</a>
<a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a>    
<a class="active" href="painting.php">Painting</a>
<a href="cleaning.php">Cleaning</a>
<a href="aircondioning.php">Air Conditioning</a>
<a href="maintenance.php">Maintenance</a> 
<a href="scaffolding.php">Scaffolding</a>      
<a href="manpower.php">Manpower Services</a> 
<a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
```

Following link on Painting page as well.

```
<a href="painting/best-interior-paint-colors-2019-trends.php">10 BEST INTERIOR PAINT COLORS TRENDING FOR 2019</a>
```

when i navigate to page best-interior-paint-colors-2019-trends.php and click on home page menu.

I see following link in browser.

http://localhost/uats/painting/uats/home.php

How can I fix this issue. I believe that browser should point to
http://localhost/uats/home.php

Please advise.

regards,

Umar Abdullah

Comment: If a menu can be used at multiple levels in the hierarchy it's probably easiest to use absolute links rather than relative e.g. `<a href="/uats/home.php">Home</a>`

Comment: Change the project folder structure or use apache `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the `href` attribute is taking the relative path. When you click on 10 BEST INTERIOR PAINT COLORS TRENDING FOR 2019 hyperlink, you move inside path `painting/best-interior-paint-colors-2019-trends.php`. Now, when you click on the Home page again, as per the href you have given, it just replaces the current file with the file `home.php`, giving you the path `painting/uats/home.php`.

To solve this, on the `best-interior-paint-colors-2019-trends.php` page, give the home href as:

```
<a href="../../home.php">Home</a>
```

Comment: I am looking for best solution. How can I fix? I can understand the problem of relative path.

Comment: @UmarAbdullah: Edited the answer providing a solution.

Comment: <a href="../home.php">Home</a> is not working because I am using sub directory uats.

Comment: @UmarAbdullah: You can use `../../` to come out of 'painting' directory and then 'uats' directory. I would rather recommend you to set the common directory 'uats' path while setting the href attribute's value for each anchor tag. Don't set it common for all pages.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when clicking the link you are navigating to the actual painting directory. In order to make your navigation "dynamic", you can do several things. One being using .htaccess rewrite rules (mod_rewrite) or far, far simpler change your URLs to proper absolute URLs like so:

```
<a href="/home.php">Home</a>
```

Notice the leading slash.

Comment: Is the project you are working on served from its own web root or from a sub directory beneath something? The leading slash will be the parent level of your sites web root. Make sense?

Comment: Its from sub directory that uats. If I use uats then its fine. I am looking for best solution so that I should not face any problem at the time of deployment.